# Kendo UI for MVC Column pulldown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, kendo-ui

My first Stack Overflow question, mainly because there are so many great answers out there for the other questions I have had.

I am looking for the simplest way to add a predefined pulldown to a column of a Kendo UI for MVC grid.  I don't think it's necessary to add a Genders table to SQL in order to ask the user Male or Female and save the choice as a string, rather than a complex type, just as if I had typed it in.  Any suggestions on the shortest and cleanest route to getting the user to choose from one of a predefined range of strings?